# Unicode characters display abnormally after TextView adds LinearGradient

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement that the end of the TextView needs a gradient, I think the way is as follows:

```
 LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, nameSize, 0
 , new int[]{Color.WHITE, Color.TRANSPARENT}, new float[]{0.91f, 1.0f}
 , Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
 mPlayName.getPaint().setShader(linearGradient);
```

The effect is as follows：
[image]

But when there are characters with Unicode, the display does not come out, such as "〖中文DJ〗 分手以后❕", The effect is as follows

[image]

the display is blank

so, How to display Unicode characters after adding LinearGradient to TextView

Comment: try using `View#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`

Comment: After setting View#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, it is displayed normally.Is this because of the hard acceleration?

Comment: hmm, it seems so

Comment: Set mPlayName.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true) directly; but no effect